# c: string to float (only with Libc)?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [string to float conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825392/string-to-float-conversion)

how can i convert a string to float in c with only Libc?

Comment: Please have a look at:
man sscanf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [strtod](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtod.html) or [sscanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sscanf.html) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *float_str = "10.5";
double d = atof(float_str);
```

or

```
char *float_str = "10.5";
double d = strtod(float_str, (char **) NULL);
```

(The second form is recommended for newer code, as `atof` is deprecated in favor of `strtod`.)

It's in the `stdlib.h` header.

Comment: hmm.. not recommended for new code... `strtod`/`strtof` is the way forward..

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Parsing-of-Floats

particularly `strtod`, `strtof`

correct link...