# Split char[] and read floats

Tags: c, arrays, split, char

I have a `char buffer[128]` which looks like:

> -0.003662 0.996887 0.012818 1.010438 0.004120 1.025911

What would be the simplest method to get each float out of this char array in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know how many floats are in your string, you could also consider [sscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

```
char buffer[128] = "-0.003662 0.996887 0.012818 1.010438 0.004120 1.025911";
float nums[6];
int numFloats = sscanf(buffer, "%f %f %f %f %f %f",
                       &nums[0], &nums[1], &nums[2], &nums[3], &nums[4], &nums[5]);
```

Comment: Since I know number of floats in the string this is perfect! Thank you.

Comment: You should check the return value of `sscanf()` to make sure you got the expected number of conversions done.

Comment: @unwind Thanks, good point, I've updated the code to show this

Answer (score 2):

U can use strtok() or strtok_r() to pasrse it- see [strtok manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok):

somthing like:

```
void parse_numbers(char *buffer) {
    char *number = NULL;

   for (number = strtok(buffer, " "); number != NULL; number = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
       do_something_with_number(conert_string_to_float(number));
   }
}
float convert_string_to_float(char *number) {
    float return_value = 0;
    sscanf(number, "%f", &return_value);
    return return_value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look at:
[Strtok refference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) and than this question: [string to float conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825392/string-to-float-conversion)